# automatic R wrapper generation for java methods

Tags: java, r

I am trying to use a `Java package` from `R`.

`RJava` provides a way to call `Java` from `R`, but wrapping all the methods is impractical.

Does anyone know of a script that generates wrappers for a package (say, by processing the relevant javadoc)?

Answer (score 5):

I could be wrong, but having used rJava fairly extensively, I'm quite sure that nothing like that exists.

While implementing my own packages with rJava, I went through the source code for many of the packages that reverse depend on it (you can see these [at the bottom of the CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html)).  None of these had anything that looked like automated code.

Incidentally, for anyone unfamiliar with it, I strongly recommend reading the vignette and looking at the source code for [the helloJavaWorld package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/helloJavaWorld/index.html); it was specifically created to help with this process.

What you're suggesting would be a very welcome improvement.  I'm happy to collaborate on creating it if anyone has interest.

*Edit*

[Romain Francois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499163/romain) just pointed out that this feature now exists in rJava (actually, as of [October 2009](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/news.html)).  Here is an example:

```
> require( rJava ) ; .jinit() 
> attach( javaImport( "java.lang" ) ) 
> Math$PI 
[1] 3.141593 
> Math$abs( -3 ) 
[1] 3
```

Once you import a class, you also get auto-completion by, for instance, Math$[tab].